# How to enable speakers sounds when I plugin a external microphone ? (OS Xubuntu 16.04.6)

Tags: audio, microphone, speakers, xubuntu

I have an external microphone and I would like to ask if is it possible to plugin this microphone then enable output sound for the speakers? So far when it's plugged the speakers sounds are disabled.
OS: Xubuntu 16.04.6
Laptop Dell inspiron 15 3521
thanks in advance, vladi

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. You can use one input device unrelated to any other output device. Meaning: you can select the internal sound card (and integrated speakers) for the output and select another device like an external USB microphone - which is an external USB sound card for all intended purposes - as the input. Or select audio via HDMI - again, a different sound card this time residing in the graphics card - for output and use a microphone connected to the internal sound card, or the USB one, or any combination of devices. (...)

Comment: (...) We don't know - because it's relevant information missing from your question - which hardware you're dealing with or what is really happening. If you have a single connection for headsets (headphones + mic) then obviously when you connect the mic it'll disable the internal speakers and this is by design because it expects something else to be connected there. Alternatively you can use a cheap external USB sound card.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'sorry, my laptop (DELL inspiron 15 3521) has a 3.5mm combo jack (for headphone & microphone), but I have only a microphone, it's not USB microphone, it's a 3.5mm jack microphone. Ok,, as you said, when microphone is connected it disables the internal speaker. (I thought, I could overpass this behaviour). thaks

Comment: Suspecting that would be the case that's why I suggested a cheap external USB sound card, as low as $1 in Aliexpress and probably something similar and not much more expensive in Amazon.